# Error on provisioning apache2 opscode cookbook on Centos 5.9 vagrant with chef-solo

Tags: apache, vagrant, chef-solo

Trying a simple apache2 provision on vagrant causes a `Permission Denied` error:

```
[2014-03-06T18:35:26+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 10.16.2 ***
[2014-03-06T18:35:26+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[chef-solo-proxy]", "recipe[yum]", "recipe[apache2]"] from JSON
[2014-03-06T18:35:26+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[chef-solo-proxy], recipe[yum], recipe[apache2]]
[2014-03-06T18:35:26+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [chef-solo-proxy, yum, apache2]
[2014-03-06T18:35:26+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for localhost.localdomain
[2014-03-06T18:35:26+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2014-03-06T18:35:26+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.

================================================================================
Error executing action `start` on resource 'service[apache2]'
================================================================================

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /sbin/service httpd start ----
STDOUT: Starting httpd: [FAILED]
STDERR: httpd: Could not open configuration file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Permission denied
---- End output of /sbin/service httpd start ----
Ran /sbin/service httpd start returned 1
```

I logged into the guest host and saw that `httpd.conf` is owned by root, shouldn't it be? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you running chef-client with root privileges? ie. `sudo chef-client`

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm new to vagrant, I assume that the vagrant provision process runs chef-solo with sudo...